# AWS database service, how to get permission to create tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently created an instance on aws database service, connected to it and was making tables on SQL and such and then all of a sudden it tells me i dont have permission to create tables anymore. where do i go to adjust this permission?

the error says 
"You are not logged on as the database owner or system administrator. You might not be able to save changes to tables that you do not own." "Certain edits require CREATE TABLE permissoins"

I was already making tables but this came on after I tried to do a schema comparison of copying a table from my computer and copy it into the aws database.

Comment: What kind of database is it?  Aurora-Mysql, Aurora-Postgres, SQL Server?

Comment: Could you please clarify how you created the database (was it with Amazon RDS?), the type of database you are using (MySQL?), and the actual error message you are receiving. Feel free to Edit your question to provide additional details. For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i up dated the question a little bit but please let me know if i need more information.